# Knowing when a person has moved to the left (right) relative to last known position

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

Is there a way in android programming to know when a person carrying an android device has moved left/right [more like shifting to the right/left] in reference to their last known position?

For example:
If I held my android device to the left of me, moving it to my right, this app should tell me that relative to the last position of the device, it has moved to the right.

Comment: try measuring geological coordinates differences if you are using map.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different ways of doing this, maybe more.

You could use the compass to find which direction the phone was pointing at the start and the end, and the accelerometer to tell you which way it moved.

Similarly you could use GPS coordinates in lieu of the accelerometer.

Both of these methods might give you false positives or might not pick it up- the first one you'd have false positives dues to jerky movement (You'd have to employ some good filtering or the data is useless) while the second would have issues where there resolution of GPS is not tight enough (say within 10 feet of starting point). GPS also doesn't work indoors.

Some devices also won't have the combination of sensors you need.  If you are more specific about the conditions and environment I might be able to edit this to give you a better answer.

Comment: I did consider using GPS but thought of that disadvantage, so am going to have to try with first method.

Comment: Yeah, here the deal though- choosing a filter to capture the 'gesture' is going to be tough.  Accelerometers are crude- you will need to do some form of windowed integration on the input of the axes, and the data WILL be noisy.